# Is `[1,2,3]` valid json format?

Tags: json, validation

I know:

```
{
   "name": "Mike",
   "age": 18
}
```

or

```
[{"name": "Mike"},{"name": "Jeff"}]
```

are valid jsons.

But I'm not sure if `[1,2,3]` is or not?

Comment: Isn't any javascript value a valid json? The first example is an object, the second example is an array of objects, and the third example is an array of integers (which does not differ much from the second one, as the arrays in JS are untyped).

Comment: @penartur Not even close. `/foo/` and `(function(){})` are valid JS values but not valid JSON. Freewind's objects are not even valid JSON (keys **must** be double quoted in JSON).

Comment: You **have** looked at the "train-tracks" on http://JSON.org, right? (-1 because there is "no question" if this had been done.)

Comment: Many people don't know this. If you ask them to read a lot before asking question, then SO should not exist

Comment: @Freewind And if existing information was *incorporated* then questions would be much better...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[1,2,3] a valid JSON array, but not a valid JSON object. An object must be of the form {...}.

<strike>Your other examples are not valid JSON. Strings must be in double-quotes.</strike> You fixed it.